# Assymetrical setup in modern F1

Tags: equipment, formula-1

Back in the day (60's, 70's and 80's) F1 cars could have assymetrical suspension setups — packers, dumpers, springs, camber, anti-roll bars etc... — which makes sense: in Imola you are mostly turning left, while in Monza you are mostly turning right.

However, modern F1 cars are a very different beast... for instance, just the other day I was quite suprised when Vettel said rain setups are a thing of the past! Gear ratio setups are another example, they don't exist anymore.

Thus, my question: do modern F1 cars still use assymetrical setups?